# Error converting Linq query to list

Tags: linq, list, entity-framework-4

Here's my code. I want to save the list in a session variable for later authentication (it's a list of objects the user is authorized to access....) I get an error saying it cannot implictly convert System.Collections.Generic.List to 'System.collections.Generic.List. Help?

```
    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strUserName = User.Identity.Name;
        string strShortUserName = strUserName.Replace("WINNTDOM\\", string.Empty).ToUpper();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["strShortUserName"] = strShortUserName;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["strUserName"] = strUserName;
        List<string> authorizedObjects = new List<string>();
        using (CPASEntities ctx = new CPASEntities())
        {
            var w = (from t in ctx.tblUsers
                     where (t.UserPassword == strUserName)
                     select t).FirstOrDefault();
            if (!(w==null))
            {
                authorizedObjects = (from t in ctx.qryUserObjectAuthorization
                                         where (t.UserPassword == strUserName)
                                         select new {  n = t.ObjectName }).ToList();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I removed the unnecessary "new" clause, and it worked. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate that as a list of strings use

```
authorizedObjects = (from t in ctx.qryUserObjectAuthorization
                     where (t.UserPassword == strUserName)
                     select t.ObjectName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

`authorizedObjects` is `List<string>` but you're trying to use it as a List of anonymous type:

```
List<string> authorizedObjects = new List<string>();
```

(...)

```
authorizedObjects = (from t in ctx.qryUserObjectAuthorization
                     where (t.UserPassword == strUserName)
                     select new {  n = t.ObjectName, i = t.ObjectID }).ToList()
```

Change your query to that:

```
authorizedObjects = (from t in ctx.qryUserObjectAuthorization
                     where (t.UserPassword == strUserName)
                     select t.ObjectName).ToList()
```

Comment: You also had the answer, and it was well-explained. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing a `List<string>` object but populating different object.

```
List<string> authorizedObjects = new List<string>();

select new {  n = t.ObjectName, i = t.ObjectID } <--construct a class with these properties and initialize `List<WithNewClassName>`
```